# Langchain error - NotImplementedError: Need to determine which default deprecation schedule to use. within ?? minor releases

Tags: python, langchain, palm

I ran the bellow code. However, currently, it shows an error massage.

```
from langchain.llms import GooglePalm

api_key = 'my_API'


llm = GooglePalm(google_api_key=api_key,
                 temperature=0.1)
```

This is the error I got.

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a3e32679669c> in <cell line: 7>()
      5 
      6 # Create llm variable here
----> 7 llm = GooglePalm(google_api_key=api_key,
      8                  temperature=0.1)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain_core/_api/deprecation.py in warn_deprecated(since, message, name, alternative, pending, obj_type, addendum, removal)
    293         if not removal:
    294             removal = f"in {removal}" if removal else "within ?? minor releases"
--> 295             raise NotImplementedError(
    296                 f"Need to determine which default deprecation schedule to use. "
    297                 f"{removal}"

NotImplementedError: Need to determine which default deprecation schedule to use. within ?? minor releases
```

Can someone please help me to solve this?

I need to create the large language model variable.

Comment: maybe you should ask authors of `langchain`. Maybe they didn't create this part of code and you have to wait for newer version. Or maybe they plan to remove it from code and you need older version.

Comment: Alright. I'll ask.

Comment: latest langchain 0.1.1 has this issue, did you find a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had a similar error, I'm using `langchain==0.1.4` in which its `google_palm` file suggests deprecation of `GooglePalm` and it is replaced with
`langchain_google_genai.GoogleGenerativeAI`

Make use of `GoogleGenerativeAI` instead;
for its installation follow these steps:

1. `pip install --upgrade --quiet langchain-google-genai`
2. `pip install -q -U google-generativeai`

Then use this code:

```
from langchain_google_genai import GoogleGenerativeAI

llm = GoogleGenerativeAI(model="models/text-bison-001", google_api_key=SECRET_KEY, temperature=0.1)
```

**Use Google Palm API key.**

Article Links:

1. [Langchain GoogleGenerativeAI](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/llms/google_ai)
2. [GoogleGenerativeAI Quick Start guide](https://ai.google.dev/tutorials/python_quickstart)

I hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Please install Langchain version `0.0.350` and it will work.

If not, run also:

```
pip install --upgrade vertexai google-cloud-aiplatform
```

As in the comment, Vertex is a paid version, you must have a Google Cloud project. However, you can use text generation for free in AI Studio: you only have to get the API key:

https://ai.google.dev/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=BRAND_Core_Brand&gad_source=1

In this case:

```
pip install google-generativeai
```

Comment: But vertex ai is a paid version, right?

Comment: Langchain version 0.0.350 didn't work for me. Still I got the same error

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue after updating langchain from version 0.0.339 to 0.0.351.
Before Updating langchain, my package version was 0.0.339 and it was working perfectly fine while using GooglePalm, but after updating it to 0.0.351 I faced the exact same error as yours The Implementation Error.
However, I managed to resolve the problem by reverting to langchain version 0.0.339.

```
pip uninstall langchain
pip install langchain==0.0.339
```

I don't know why it is not working in langchain 0.0.351 but you can downgrade langchain untill we figure out.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue please check with the lower version

```
langchain==0.0.284
langchain==0.0.339
```

Answer (score 0):

latest langchain 0.1.1 also has this issue, as work around I have switched to text-bison model

llm = GoogleGenerativeAI(model="models/text-bison-001", google_api_key=api_key)